# Android Espresso IntentsMatcher works on new device but not old

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I have an Espresso unit test that seems to work on newer devices but fails on an API 17 device. Here is the test:

```
Intents.init()
[... more setup]
onView(withId(R.id.username))
        .perform(typeText("username"))
        .perform(closeSoftKeyboard())
onView(withId(android.R.id.button1)).perform((click()))

// This part fails
intended(hasComponent(AcceptedActivity::class.java.name))
```

The error is:

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.
```

I've tried sleeping the thread for 1000ms before `intended` is called, but that doesn't seem to help.

Any ideas why it succeeds on some devices but not the older one?

Comment: My immediate thought would be that the id android.R.id.button1 is not consistently used across devices/android API level.  This often happens when using the AppCompat libraries since the underlying code in the support library branches extensively by API level.  Can you match on text instead? or modify your application code so that you can use an ID that you control?

Comment: @jdonmoyer I had the same thought, but we have a different test that uses `android.R.id.button1` on API 17 and that one works fine. Also, if it couldn't find the button I would expect the failure to occur one line earlier.

Comment: Can you share the application code that constructs the ui and fires the intent?